# "Invalid arguments passed" but it's already defined?

Tags: php

What is the problem with this code?
When I pass it without all the table stuff it works fine. But when I add the `implode()` call, it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
    <table>
<?php

$tem=array(21, 20, 20, 20, 22, 22, 21, 19, 19, 18, 20, 18, 17, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 17, 17, 12, 12, 16, 16, 18, 18, 18, 19, 15);
rsort($tem);
$toptemp=array_slice($tem, 0,5);
foreach($toptemp as $t) {
  echo ("<tr><td>");
  echo implode ("</td><td>", $t);
  echo ("</td></tr>");
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: What does var_dump($t) tell you in the for each block?

Comment: Where should i post it exactly? After the foreach tag, or inside the foreach?

Comment: Your code appears to be correct.  It looks like $tem isn't what you think it is though.  It should be a multidimensional array for this code to work.

`print_r($tem)` will let you see very quickly if you have the correct data.

Comment: $tem is a list of numbers, 
$tem=array(21, 20, 20, 20, 22, 22, 21, 19, 19, 18, 20, 18, 17, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 17, 17, 12, 12, 16, 16, 18, 18, 18, 19, 15);

Comment: When i remove everything after $t) and just echo the output it works great. But as soon as i add the implode, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $toptemp=array_slice($tem, 0,5);
> foreach($toptemp as $t) {
>   echo ("<tr><td>");
>   echo implode ("</td><td>", $t);
>   echo ("</td></tr>");
> }
> ```

Every time you loop over the array, `$t` will take the value of each *element* of the array, which in your case would be an integer. The problem is that `implode()` expects the second parameter to be an array, not an integer.

Just get rid of the loop:

```
echo ("<tr><td>");
echo implode ("</td><td>", $toptemp);
echo ("</td></tr>");
```